# Fail to send JSON HTTP POST, but succeed to send text HTTP POST. why?

Tags: javascript, json, post, fetch-api, cloudflare

I want to send a JSON http POST from an HTML page. The Fetch API is used here.
It can be successfully posted if the content-type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or "text/plain", but fails to post if the content-type is "application/json". I have tried Both Fetch and Axios API. But JSON can be posted successfully posted from an online http tool (https://reqbin.com/)
[image]

Here is my client code in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id ="h1">post test</h1>
<input type="submit" value="post" onclick="sendpost()">
<script>
    function sendpost()
    {
        const Url = 'https://my-worker.sgcloud.workers.dev/';

        const data = {
            name: 'moe',
            age: '50'
        };

        fetch(Url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
            .then(response => response.text()
                .then(text => {
                    document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML = text;
                }))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error in development tool is:

```
POST https://my-worker.sgcloud.workers.dev/ net::ERR_FAILED
```

The server is in my cloudflare workers: https://my-worker.sgcloud.workers.dev/ , Access-Control-Allow-Origin is on. You can try to post to my server.
the server code is:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request));
});

async function handleRequest(request) {
  if (request.method == 'GET') {
  return new Response('Hello Worker!', {
    headers: { 'content-type': 'text/plain', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
  });
  } else if (request.method == 'POST') {
  return new Response('Response for POST!', {
    headers: { 'content-type': 'text/plain', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
  });
  } else {
    response = new Response('Expected POST', { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

because I can post json from the online tool, so my client code should have some problem to send application/json (the client code can send text/plain or application/x-www-form-urlencoded, tested). How shoud I change my code to send json? Thank you

Comment: It could be an adblocker or other software modifying requests. There's no problems with your code, it's with your network.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I know the reason.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

For Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) situation:
Additionally, for HTTP request methods that can cause side-effects on server data (in particular, HTTP methods other than GET, or POST with certain MIME types), the specification mandates that browsers "preflight" the request, soliciting supported methods from the server with the HTTP OPTIONS request method, and then, upon "approval" from the server, sending the actual request.

Some requests don't trigger a CORS preflight. Those are called simple requests.
The only type/subtype combinations allowed for the media type specified in the Content-Type header are:
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
multipart/form-data
text/plain.

application/json is not a simple request. so I can not post json for CORS situation, but can post text.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).